# reCAPTCHA failed request more than passed request

Tags: recaptcha, grecaptcha

I am using Google reCAPTCHA for form validation. I have got many customers complaint the image selections are too difficult. From the Google reCAPTCHA report, I saw the failed request more than passed request. Is this common?
So question here,

1. Is there a way to monitor this kind of situation or improve it?
2. If I stuck into the image selection, is there any way I can get back to normal tick captcha?

Thanks.

You can get the details from the picture, the fail is more than pass.

[image]

Picture for spam index and average response time:

[image]

Comment: Since I am not allowed to post images, here add more info: my spam index is higher than global span index, the average response time is also very long, more than 30s. In the post please click the link to see the screenshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can tune the difficulty in `Security Preference`, under `Advanced Settings` of the reCAPTCHA settings of your site.
2. Not really, since image selection only appears when reCAPTCHA thinks the tick is not enough to determine the user is a human.

Comment: From the images, is this normal the failed request more than passed

Comment: It very much depends on your use case and your audience, for me I have a very high 
`no CAPTCHAs` rate, then failed request more than passed. You can tune down the security level if you think it is suitable.